# Error 500 after connecting to Redis in Jmeter

Tags: groovy, redis, jmeter

I have a question about Groovy scripting in Jmeter.

I have created a function in Groovy that connects to Redis DB, and the function works as expected.

Afterwards, when from "main" I try to get data, it says that he is not familiar with get from Redis.

My purpose is to create the first function that connects to Redis, the second one that creates Redis key, and the third one to get data using the Redis key.

in the "main" I call `connect` and it works, but the third one does not work. Is it because the connection is closed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show all you code ? and mention the failing one ?

Comment: And maybe post code, rather than screenshots of code

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your code it is hard to guess what is wrong, according to the error message `jedis` variable is not defined in the scope, you are trying to access it. you can try defining it globally like:

```
def jedis = null; // make "jedis" variable available to all methods

void connect() {
    jedis = new Jedis(vars.get('Redis_IP', vars.get('Redis_Port') as int)
} 

void somethingElse () {
    if (jedis != null) {
        log.info(jedis.ping())
    }
}
```

A couple of points to consider:

- Don't inline [JMeter Variables or Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into script body, it makes compilation caching feature aimpossible so the overall performance of your code will be lower. Also variables might resolve into something causing script interpretation failure or unexpected behaviour. Either use "Parameters" section or go for code-based equivalents as in my above demo
- It is recommended to use JMeter built-in features (or plugins) where possible as even well-behaved Groovy script doesn't perform that fast as "normal" Java code. Check out if [Redis Data Set](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/) is matching your use case and if it does - simply install it using JMeter Plugins Manager and start using instead of struggling with Groovy.

  [image: JMeter Redis Data Set]

See [JMeter’s Redis Data Set - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) article for step-by-step instructions on the plugin installation and usage